# Accessing Meta Values from WP Database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I understand that `get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, false )` will get me the array I'm looking for in my wordpress database, but what if there is an array inside an array that's separated by colons and commas.  For example:

**Code**

```
$user_id = 2;
$key = 'the_key';
$ckey = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, false );
```

**Database**

Meta Key (meta_key)

> 'the_key'

Meta Value (meta_value)

> {"arrayTitle1":"arrayAnswer1","arrayTitle2":"arrayAnswer2","arrayTitle3":"arrayAnswer3","arrayTitle4":"arrayAnswer4"}

I've gotten as far as `echo $ckey[0];` but that only returns the entire meta value.  I've tried a combination of `echo $ckey[0][1];` and/or `echo $ckey[0]['arrayTitle1];`.

Anything can help. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is JSON format, use json_decode($jsondata, true); to return an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Andrew Schultz pointed it out, it's JSON rather than normal string.

in order to get your array working just fine you're gonna have to decode your json encoded array using `json_decode()`

that should return an array which you can access easing specifying its index...

```
$a = json_decode(get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, false ));
echo $a['your_index'];
```